# Drag'n'drop of multiple files into browser only works in Firefox - not in Chrome or Edge

Tags: javascript, file-upload

```js
        function allowDropFiles(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        function readFile(file) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var fr = new FileReader();
                fr.onload = () => {
                    resolve(fr.result)
                };
                fr.onerror = reject;
                fr.readAsDataURL(file);
            });
        }

        async function DropFiles(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var vVoucherArray = [];
            var vFileNameArray = [];
            var vFileContentArray = [];
            voucherNo = event.target.id.substring(4, event.target.id.length);
            if (event.dataTransfer.items) {
                for (var i = 0; i < event.dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
                    if (event.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === "file") {
                        const file = event.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile();
                        if (file != null) {
                            vVoucherArray.push(voucherNo);
                            vFileNameArray.push(file.name);
                            vFileContentArray.push(await readFile(file));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                for (var i = 0; i < event.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
                    const file = event.dataTransfer.files[i];
                    vVoucherArray.push(voucherNo);
                    vFileNameArray.push(file.name);
                    vFileContentArray.push(await readFile(file));
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
<div id="div0" ondrop="DropFiles(event)" ondragover="allowDropFiles(event)" style="height:100px; width:100px; background-color:red" title="Drop bilag her">
```

I have a strange problem with the code below. My aim is to upload multiple files at once to the website via Javascript. And it works very well in Firefox - but not in Chrome and Microsoft Edge.

The error message in Chrome and Microsoft Edge is: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

I can see that `event.dataTransfer.items.length` have the right number of files which I want to upload - but Chrome/Edge only uploads the first file, and then stop working :-(

So my question is: Is this a bug in these two browsers or do I need to code it differently to acomplish this task?

Any help is appreciated.

Regards Michael

```
function readFile(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = () => {
            resolve(fr.result)
        };
        fr.onerror = reject;
        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}

async function DropFiles(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var vVoucherArray = [];
    var vFileNameArray = [];
    var vFileContentArray = [];
    voucherNo = event.target.id.substring(4, event.target.id.length);
    if (event.dataTransfer.items) {
        for (var i = 0; i < event.dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
            if (event.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === "file") {
                const file = event.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile();
                if (file != null) {
                    vVoucherArray.push(voucherNo);
                    vFileNameArray.push(file.name);
                    vFileContentArray.push(await readFile(file));
                }
            }
        }
        doUploadFile(vVoucherArray, vFileNameArray, vFileContentArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you a snippet online for test it?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini what is a "snippet online" ?

Comment: A online web page where test the code..

Comment: @SimoneRossaini No I do not have the online web page - only my website which I test in localhost - and with my browsers installed.

Comment: Ok so, you need to create one i think you can use snippet here (edit question click on the icon `[<>]` and paste html/css/js)

Comment: For help on creating code snippets see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do on meta.

Comment: Are the lengths of ` vVoucherArray, vFileNameArray, vFileContentArra` arrays the same in all browsers or do they have an unexpectedly length (of 1) in webkit browsers? What does `doUploadFile` look like:? In other words what convinces you that the error is in the posted code?

Comment: @traktor doUploadFile only uploads the files via a WebMethod in C# -so maybe I should have removed this line for better understanding.

Comment: @traktor The arrays  vVoucherArray, vFileNameArray, vFileContentArray have an unexpectedly length of 1 :-(

Comment: I can't say why the drops are not working in webkit, but I can attest that using  [`dataTansfer.files`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/files) to retrieve a file list of dropped files works when multiple files are dropped in both Firefox and Edge. If not an answer, perhaps a work around?

Comment: The problem focuses on "await readFile", in fact removing it works correctly the script

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Thanks for commenting. I have tried to remove await - but now nothing will be uploaded :-(

Comment: Please accept @traktor's answer below: It explains what the problem is, and provides a working solution.

Answer (score 3):

### Drag'n'drop of multiple files into browser not working in Chrome or Edge is a bug*.

What's happening with the posted code is that `event.dataTransfer.items` and `event.dataTransfer.files` are being destroyed by setting their lengths to zero, besides replacing them, as property values of the `dataTranfer` object, with empty list objects when event handling code returns to the event loop.   To complete the destruction, the functionality of calling `getAsFile` on an item when event handling code is resumed is removed. Overall a successful effort in rendering access by the event handler to the drag and drop data store after resuming execution impossible.

This occurs in WebKit browsers (Edge tested for this answer) but not in Firefox. Returning to the event loop is occuring during execution of the `await` operator, specifically when `await readFile(file)` is evaluated.

Under WebKit, when the `for` loop is resumed by `await`, the loop condition is false because `i` is 1, and both `dataTransfer.items.length` and `dataTransfer.files.length` are 0 - causing the loop to break at the end of the first iteration.

#### Why

The main potential reason for doing this that comes to mind is to invalidate `window.event` after return to the event loop. Although now fully deprecated, using  `window.event` instead of an `event` object parameter value passed to event handles was how early versions of Microsoft IE worked. In modern browsers such usage it no longer thread safe because JavaScript execution can now be interrupted and resumed using the same execution context by the `await` operator.

Another issue could be the use of a single, static data store for all drag'n'drop operations - which if the case would make the entire drag and drop design non re-entrant.

#### Solution

Since the length of the original `files` and/or `items` lists in the event object are being set to zero, copying the file objects before attempting to read them provides a solution. Here's a snippet I used to explore and get it working:

```js
"use strict";
function allowDropFiles(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
async function DropFiles(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var files = [];
    var vVoucherArray = [];
    var vFileNameArray = [];
    var vFileContentArray = [];
    var voucherNo = event.target.id.substring(4, event.target.id.length);
    const items = event.dataTransfer.items;
    if (items) {
        console.log( "items: ", items.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if( items[i].kind === 'file') {
                files.push(items[i].getAsFile());
            }
        }
        console.log( files);
    }
    for( var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
        var file = files[i];
        if (file) {
            vVoucherArray.push(voucherNo);
            vFileNameArray.push(file.name);
            vFileContentArray.push(await readFile(file));
        }
    }
    doUploadFile(vVoucherArray, vFileNameArray, vFileContentArray);
}

function readFile(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = () => {
            resolve(fr.result)
        };
        fr.onerror = reject;
        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}
function doUploadFile(vouchers, fileNames, fileContent){
    console.log(vouchers,fileNames);
    var total =0;
    fileContent.forEach(text=>total+= text.length);
    console.log("Total bytes: " + total);
}
```

```html
<div id="div0" ondrop="DropFiles(event)" ondragover="allowDropFiles(event)" style="height:100px; width:100px; background-color:red" title="Drop bilag her">
```

The snippet has been kept close to the post and iterates through the items array checking for `kind==="file"` to filter entries. A simpler option may be to clone the files list using the equivalent of:

```
const files = Array.from(event.dataTransfer.files);
```

### *Is it really a bug

I'd call it a bug to solve a reentrancy problem by making sure it will fail when in doubt. Vendors probably may not agree - hinting that `dataTranfer` objects can be disassociated from a drag data store in [HTML standards](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dnd.html#the-datatransferitem-interface) is another way of saying it's documented behaviour and not their problem if developers get bitten by it (IMHO).

Comment: This is the correct answer. **The solution is to extract all `event.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile()` before the first call to `await`** (or equally before launching any other asynchronous callbacks, e.g. directly via `Promise`-based functions). The same issue and solution also exists with functions such as [`webkitGetAsEntry()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem/webkitGetAsEntry).

Comment: Technically: The issue might also be related to the DnD event [`Drag data store mode`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dnd.html#dndevents) which constrains during which event handlers `dataTransfer.items` can be used. I suspect that Chrome (v109 for me) takes this protection so far as to wipe `event.dataTransfer.items` outside of the immediate call to the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use `readFile()` etc. use `formData` like:

```js
function allowDropFiles(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
let formData = new FormData();
async function DropFiles(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.dataTransfer.items) {
    for (var i = 0; i < event.dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
      if (event.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === "file") {
        const file = event.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile();
        if (file != null) {
          formData.append("file", file);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  for (const value of formData.values()) {
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div0" ondrop="DropFiles(event)" ondragover="allowDropFiles(event)" style="height:100px; width:100px; background-color:red" title="Drop bilag her">
```

Reference:

- [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)